# First lens for astrophotography

Tags: canon, astrophotography, ultra-wide, samyang

I'm only starting with astrophotography, and need some advice on which lens to buy for my Canon 250D (SL3). Currently i have only kit lens and Canon 50mm f1.8 stm. The idea was to start from something wide, like from this list:

- Rokinon FE14M-C 14mm F2.8 (329$ on amazon) or Samyang SY14M-C 14mm F2.8
- Rokinon Series II 14mm F2.8 Weather Sealed (449$)
- Samyang 14mm F2.8 AF Wide Angle (499$)

Since I'm not sure if this new hobby will last long, I'm thinking about the last one with autofocus so I can at least use it for something else.

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Also related: [How can I do astrophotography with my 70-300mm lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/46536/15871) and [Affordable lenses for nightscape photography (nikon d5300)?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/77049/15871) and [How do I choose a lens to photograph the Milky Way?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/48809/15871)

Comment: Photography is art and although there's good rules of thumb and concepts to understand and learn, the important thing is that it works for you.  You could use a wide angle to capture a night sky or a 50mm or higher to capture just parts of the sky depending on what sort of photos you want to get.  You can do this how you want :)

Comment: Yes. But there not every lens suits for astrophotography. So the question was rather if the last lens with autofocus is as good as the first two. And is paying for the AF for other types of photography worth it? Or I should just buy the cheapest one with manual focus.